# Entity Framework 5 Ninject error

Tags: entity-framework-5, ninject, runtime-error, console-application

### I'm dealing with this error:

> An exception ocurred with the initializer of type
>   *'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig'*

### Using:

1. Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
2. Entity Framework 5.0

### Description:

I have a console application that injects some dependencies from these layers:
-Domain
-DAL 
-Services

### I use these patterns:

-Unit of Work
-Repository 
-Inversion of Control

And a console application tries to injects the dependencies and query my database.

### Here is my **connectionString** in *App.config*:

```
<add name="ClockContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Clock.LocalDb;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

### Here is my context class:

```
public class ClockContext : DbContext
{
    //ClockContext
    public IDbSet<StampUnit> Stamps{ get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

### Here is the Program syntax:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //stamps: A collection that loads data from  other source

        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new StampsInitializerModule());
        var service = kernel.Get<IStampService>();//Here throws the exception
        foreach (var stamp in stamps)
        {
            var stampUnit = new StampUnit
            {
                ClockId = stamp.ClockId,
                WorkerId = stamp.WorkerId,
                Start = stamp.Start,
                End = stamp.End,
            };
            service.CreateStamp(stampUnit);//database query
            Console.WriteLine(stampUnit);
        }
    }
}
```

### Here is the Ninject's module syntax:

```
   class StampsInitializerModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbContext>().To<ClockContext>();

        //DbFactory DI
        Bind<IDbFactory>().To<DbFactory>();

        //UnitOfWork DI
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();


        #region Repositories DI

        Bind<IStampRepository>().To<StampRepository>();

        #endregion


        #region Services DI

        Bind<IStampService>().To<StampService>();   

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Examine the InnerExceptions of the TypeInitializationException you are getting and then provide more details. Very likely the issue is not related to Ninject but rather some misconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Following instructions from [@cvbarros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655900/cvbarros), thanks again. 
I checked my **InnerMessage** when debugging, and there were some problems with the *App.config* file. 
Because, previously I was using SqlCompact for testing my data, and without pause I changed to LocalDb, so it was required adding these lines in order to the app could function.

### These were missed:

- configSections
- connectionString
- defaultConnectionFactory

### Added

```
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

### Added

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Clock.DoReading.Properties.Settings.Setting" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Clock.LocalDb;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

### Added

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>    
  </entityFramework>
```